# Getting a particular value from an input inside a loop

Tags: php, jquery

I am getting a list of products from the database through a loop. The productId is placed in a hidden input. This input is placed in a div. What i need to do is get the value of a particular through Jquery.

below is my code

```
var t = document.getElementById('txtPID').value;
```

The thing is that the value that I get is the value found in the first input. (the first ProductId found in the page).

What can i do to get that particular value in the input using Jquery?

Comment: I see no PHP here, why the [php] tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question was this:

```
echo "<div class=".content." rel=".mssql_guid_string($ProdId).">";
echo $row['Quantity'];
```

echo "";

And for the jquery part:

```
        $(function () {
        $(".content").click(function () {
                var a = $(this).attr('rel');
            })
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP:

```
intval($varchar);
```

Or if that's easier Javascript:

```
parseInt(varchar);
```

Comment: Sorry but I did not quite understand. isn't that prasing from var to integer?

Comment: You should also check that its valid, check out is_numeric() or ctype_digit()

Comment: My problem is that there is more than one input with the same id name therefore the value I am getting is that of the first input......

Comment: I don't need to parse the value. My problem is getting the value in the first place

Comment: @user1133200 get a username, your question is titled "conversion of varchar to int in php", so yes the answer is converting VARCHAR to INT

Comment: Each ID in HTML has to be unique. Use classes if you want to group elements.

Comment: @Prof83I appologies for my mistake in the title must have been already there.

Comment: I'm new to php and I still don't know how to use classes in php

Comment: You seem to mix HTML, PHP and jQuery. I ment HTML classes.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have assigned the same `id` to multiple `inputs`.

Make sure they are unique, e.g.:

```
$input = '<input type="hidden" id="id-'.$yourProductId.'" value="'.$yourProductId.'" />';
```

Comment: I can't because its a loop. since i am getting a list of products and placing each product id in an input

Comment: @user1133200: Fix your loop then.

Comment: How will i get the value of the id then?

Comment: Can you show the actual HTML Output and how you access it via Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var t = document.getElementById('txtPID').value;
var myInt = parseInt(t);
```

for more info check the link http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp

Comment: my problem is that the input is inside a loop therefore the inputs have the same ID

Comment: @Michelle then please update your question and show your loop's code so that easy to understand to all.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [intval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) function in **php**.

If you are using **jquery** then, you can use [parseInt()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp)

Answer (score 0):

An HTML element ID is supposed to be unique.  The whole point of an id is that it's used to identify a particular element in the DOM.  Javascript's getElementByID is dependant on all IDs in the DOM being unique.

If you have more than one element with the same ID then the behaviour of getElementByID is undefined.  This means that using it might return the first matching element.  Or it might return the last matching element.  Or it might return any one of the elements in the DOM with a matching ID.  It might even make demons fly out of your nose, as the behaviour is undefined anything that getElementByID does at this point can't be considered incorrect.

The first thing you have to do before you can even attempt to make your JS work is fix the page markup so that all IDs in the DOM really are unique.  You can't build javascript that works reliably on top of an invalid DOM>

Comment: I am looping these inputs and therefore all inputs will automatically take the same ID.  Since what i am trying to do is when the user click on a particular button I get the product Id of that same row

Comment: Like I just explained, you can only have 1 item of a given ID in the DOM.  If you have more than one, then there's no sensible way of distinguishing between them.